# How do I eliminate multiple joins of the same table in a has_many through association with multiple scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Given the following models and associations:

```
class Employee
   has_many :positions
   has_many :titles, :through => :positions
   scope :is_active, -> { joins(:positions).merge(Position.is_active) }
   scope :title_is, ->(name) { joins(:titles).merge(Title.id_or_name_is(name)) }
end

class Position
   belongs_to :employee
   belongs_to :title
   # bool 'active' to indicate whether the position is active or not
   scope :is_active, -> { where("active = true") }
end

class Title
   has_many :positions
   has_many :employees, :through => :positions
   scope :id_or_name_is, ->(id_or_name) { where("titles.id = ? OR titles.name = ?", id_or_name, id_or_name) if id_or_name}
end
```

`Employee.is_active` returns the correct number of results and generates the correct query. However, when I attempt to do `Employee.title_is(123).is_active` (which I want to return all employees where the `title_id` is 123 and are active, it results in multiple joins with position. This is no problem except that the is active check only applies to one of the position joins thereby resulting in both active positions and inactive positions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `employees`
    INNER JOIN `positions` ON `positions`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `positions` `positions_employees_join` ON positions_employees_join`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `titles` ON titles`.`id` = `positions_employees_join`.`title_id` 
WHERE positions.active = true)
      AND (titles.id = 123 OR 
      titles.name = 123)
```

I should also note that technically if I also had a way of adding in the where clause `positions_employees_join.active = true`, then it would work correctly as well, though I don't know how I would do that in my scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would skip using the `titles` association in the `title_is` scope.

```
scope :title_is, ->(name) { joins(:positions => :title).merge(Title.is_or_name_is(name)) }
```

Keep the association because it still gives you more efficient queries when calling `employee_instance.titles` rather than `employee_instance.positions.titles`.

But for the purpose of your scope, doing `joins(:positions => :title)` tells ActiveRecord that you want to use the regular join from other scopes that call `joins(:positions)`.

Comment: Whoops. My bad. I didn't look too closely at your associations in the `Position` model.

I've updated the answer to reflect your comments. Thanks :)